# How to print binary number as hexdecimal?

Tags: c, function, binary

I have a binary number, and I need to print it as hexdecimal number. (its a function in a bigger project)

I made this function, but I was only able to print it in reverse.
this is  the function:

```
int printOctalToHex (unsigned int octalNum) {
    unsigned int binaryNum;
    int temp;
    int i = 1;
    binaryNum = octalToBinary(octalNum);
    while (1) {
        temp = (binaryNum % 10000);
        binaryNum = binaryNum / 10000;

        if (temp == 0) {
            printf("0");
        }
        if (temp == 1) {
            printf("1");
        }
        if (temp == 10) {
            printf("2");
        }
        if (temp == 11) {
            printf("3");
        }
        if (temp == 100) {
            printf("4");
        }
        if (temp == 101) {
            printf("5");
        }
        if (temp == 110) {
            printf("6");
        }
        if (temp == 111) {
            printf("7");
        }
        if (temp == 1000) {
            printf("8");
        }
        if (temp ==1001) {
            printf("9");
        }
        if (temp == 1010) {
            printf("A");
        }
        if (temp == 1011) {
            printf("B");
        }
        if (temp == 1100) {
            printf("C");
        }
        if (temp == 1101) {
            printf("D");
        }
        if (temp == 1110) {
            printf("E");
        }
        if (temp == 1111) {
            printf("F");
        }
        if (binaryNum < 1) {
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

}
```

Can someone help me with that please? TY!

And if someone has a better way to do it I will be happy to see, because my way is very long.

Comment: Instead of using a variable to store numbers only using decimal `1`s and `0`s, just store the number like a regular number. It's they binary automatically and you can fish out the 2 nibbles from each byte with `(byte & 0xF0) >> 8` and `byte & 0x0F`. With that you have two indices, `0`-`15`, that you can use to look up the corresponding character in an array.

Comment: use ```sprintf``` like ```unsigned int binary = 0xabcd;
   
 char buff[32]={0};
 
sprintf(buff,"%x",binary);```

Comment: Please add a [mre] by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: This task doesn't make any sense. All integers in C are already in binary. We can convert them to _strings_ expressed in other bases before printing, or write source code in other bases for the programmer's convenience. `1010` is one thousand and ten, decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You need just two functions, one of which is a recursive function:

```
int f_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return 1;
}

void f_hex(int nb)
{
    char *hex = "0123456789abcdef";
    if (nb < 16)
    {
        f_putchar(hex[nb]);
    }
    else
    {
        f_hex(nb / 16);
        f_hex(nb % 16);
    }
}
```